# can I reopen stream after closing it in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, rxjs, rx-java, rxdart

In my Flutter app, I use a `BehaviorSubject()` to listen to an email text field.
when user successfully log in I called dispose function to close it to avoid memory leaks.

In case of the user signs out and tries to log in again, **can I reopen the stream**  ?

```
final _emailStream = BehaviorSubject<String>.seeded("");
final validateEmail = StreamTransformer<String, String>.fromHandlers(handleData: (email, sink) {
    var isEmailValid = RegExp(
            r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+")
        .hasMatch(email);
    isEmailValid ? sink.add(email) : sink.addError("Enter a valid Email");
  });
Stream<String> get email => _emailStream.stream.transform(validateEmail);
void updateEmail(String email) => _emailStream.sink.add(email);
void dispose() {
    _emailStream.close();
    
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't re-open a stream.

However, in my current project, I open the stream when I build my login class. So when I login, I dispose my streams, and when I log out the bloc containing my streams is rebuild and new streams are re-created.

Probably not the best way, but it works for me!

[Log out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnH6J.png)

[Building formbloc containing my streams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CxIy.png)